# xamarin forms consume wcf service issue when changing the address at runtime

Tags: android, visual-studio, wcf, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio (most recent v4.0.30319) and targeting Android platform only.  Trying to consume a wcf service, so adding the address of the service at design time (Add service reference).  Lets say it is called MyService.svc and its runs locally on the machine at address 192.168.100.1, the the Add Service Reference url is http://192.168.100.1/MyService.svc.  The Add Service Reference dialog finds the service and adds it to the PCL project.  No problem so far.

In the code the service is consumed by default as follows:
var client = new MyServiceClient();

When the android application starts, everything works, the service can be called and data is returned from the service as expected.  Great stuff! So far so good.

However, here is where the problems start.  Having the address for the service configured at runtime doesn't make it very scale-able.  So the address of the service needs to be adjusted at runtime for different systems.  A simple settings page allows the user to enter the service address in the app, Idea being that the service will point at that endpoint address instead of the default 'configured at design time' address.
So we tried the following code as documented:

```
var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
{
    Name = "basicHttpBinding",
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
    MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
    SendTimeout = timeout,
    OpenTimeout = timeout,
    ReceiveTimeout = timeout,
};                  

var endPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.100.1/MyService.svc");
var client = new MyServiceClient(binding, endPoint);
```

Even with it being the same address as the design time configured service, we receive the error 'There was no endpoint listening at {0} that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.'.  Drilling into the inner exceptions just gives a 'NOT FOUND' web exception.  Removing the endPoint variable from the call then works again (as it reverts back to the design time address).

Any guru's out there could help us get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working.

Inspecting the Endpoint.Address just after var client = new MyServiceClient() showed the url as 'http://192.168.100.1/MyService.svc/MyServices.svc', Don't understand why the svc name part is in there twice and also pluralised, but it works now....